# Are 'Strategic resources' automatically shown on the map?

Tags: stellaris

If a technology is researched to reveal a resource, will the new resource be shown automatically on the maps? or does it required a new/special survey of the entire empire?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you've already surveyed the system a new resource is in, then it shows up right away. If you've already built a mining station there, then you have access to it right away.

I can't find a good citation for these facts, but I've played the game for dozens of hours and can assure you that it is the case. I believe there's also an in-game tip to this effect.

At the top of the screen, to the right of your technology income, there is a white diamond-shaped icon.

[image]

Next to the icon are numbers representing how many total resources you have access to, and how many of those are currently available for use. Hovering over the icon shows you those same numbers, but for each individual type of resource. Thanks to @toolkitxx for pointing out the icon, and @Sjoerd for providing a picture.

When you are trying to build something that requires one of these strategic resources, a red X on the thing that you're trying to build indicates that you don't have the resource available in the same sector.

Comment: Can you confirmed that you witnessed this in one of your galaxies?

Comment: @ShloEmi "I've played the game for dozens of hours and can assure you that it is the case."

Comment: @DCShannon There is a little icon on top of your screen that lists all strategic resources that you have available and how many of those are used. Just hover your mouse above the icon

Comment: **Strategic resources show up on the map right away, with no need to rescout** - I can confirm that. They even appear in systems you got through map trading, even if the faction you got the map from doesn't know about the resource yet.

If you're already mining the body on which they appear, you get access to the newly discovered resource for free. There is no need to upgrade your mining equipment.

The icon at the top of the screen only lists the resources you are mining, and how many are mined but unused. There is no list of "known locations" available, so scanning the map is required.

Comment: Is it possible that the resource will appear on a planet with a resource-station?

Comment: @toolkitxx The icon shows how many strategic resources you are _mining_ (and how many of them are unused). I don't think they show, if they're just there, unmined. They _defenately_ don't show there if they're controlled by another empire.

Comment: In two of my games, by the time I finished researching my 1st Strategic Resource, I'd already built a mining station above one of the worlds containing it.

Comment: @Sjoerd: That works for resources you have mined. (If you've built a mining station on a planet that later turns out to have Betharian, you'll immediately get access to it.) It doesn't work for resources you haven't mined--there's no info saying that you have access to Betharian in your space that's unmined. Thankfully, the strategic resources mostly land on things you would have been harvesting anyway.

Comment: @MatthewGraves I don't understand your comment. You seem to agree with me, as I wrote "The icon at the top of the screen only lists the resources you are mining, and how many are mined but unused."

Comment: @Sjoerd I think they're saying that if you have territory control over a system, but no mining station on the Betharian planet, there's nothing in the top bar that indicates you have a *potential* strategic resource that you're just not mining at present. Instead you've got to look at the map (possibly in Advanced mode) to see the white-number strategic resource icon and realize that you're not mining it yet.

Comment: Which is why I wrote "There is no list of "known locations" available, so scanning the map is required." I still fail to see where Matthew disagrees with me.